# Tensorflow - post training integer quantization

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision

I am trying to perform post training integer quantization to a model trained in Tensorflow 2.8.0, following the instructions [mentioned here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_integer_quant) with some adaptations. I have all my images in a directory called "**customTF2/data/images**". I can't figute out though how to generate a representative dataset needed for the quantization. The official documentation, as well as the majority of examples found online, use either Tensorflow datasets or datasets where the images are already labelled and split into relevent subfolders (which is not the case for my project). Below is my code

```
def representative_data_gen():
  test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)
  test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('customTF2/data', 
      target_size=(300, 300), 
      batch_size=1,
      classes=['images'],
      class_mode='categorical')
  for ind in range(len(test_generator.filenames)):
    img_with_label = test_generator.next()
    yield [np.array(img_with_label[0], dtype=np.float32, ndmin=2)]


converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model('customTF2/data/tflite/new/saved_model')
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.representative_dataset = representative_data_gen
# Ensure that if any ops can't be quantized, the converter throws an error
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
converter.target_spec.supported_types = [tf.int8]
# Set the input and output tensors to uint8 (APIs added in r2.3)
converter.inference_input_type = tf.uint8
converter.inference_output_type = tf.uint8

tflite_model_quant = converter.convert()
```

which fails with the error : **Given shapes, [1,20,20,128] and [1,19,19,128], are not broadcastable.Node number 68 (ADD) failed to prepare.**

Not sure how I should perform the quantization for that dataset or how the previous code needs to be updated. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to verify whether the shape of the processed images is the same as that of the input layer of your model.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Indeed the issue was that I was setting my image dimensions to 300x300, while the model (SSD Mobilenet V2) requires 320x320.